# Just got my contract drained- how?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, hack

I just got my contract drained, and am trying to understand how. Obviously I'm a noob, played with fire and got burned bad (shouldn't have big sums of money on contracts). I SHOULD have transferred my funds in every transaction from my EOA. I'm still in shock and numb. Can anyone please help me identify the vulnerability? I want to grow past this, I have to. I'm also happy for any input on how I can improve this contract in general, thank you!

The attacker used a different contract he created, he didn't call my contract directly. The logs show an approval for the total amount from my contract to his, a single transfer to a third address (from my contract), and an approval of 0 from my contract to his (the logs are in this order).

```
contract arb {
 ICurve constant curve = ICurve(0xxxx);
 Itest constant test = Itest(0xxxx);
 address owner;

    constructor() {
           IERC20 token1 = IERC20(0xxxx);
           IERC20 token2 = IERC20(0xxxx);
           token1.approve(0xxxx, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935);
           token1.approve(0xxxx, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935);
           token2.approve(0xxxx, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935);
           token2.approve(0xxxx, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935);
           owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner(){
    require(msg.sender == owner, "You know why");
    _;
}

function approve(address token, address spender, uint amount) public returns (bool success){
    IERC20 t = IERC20(token);
    return t.approve(spender, amount);
}
function transfer(address token, uint amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool success){
    IERC20 t = IERC20(token);
    return t.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
}
function arb1(uint amt) public{
    uint amt_out = curve.exchange(0, 1, amt, 0);
    uint amt_out2 = test.xxx1(amt_out, 0);
    require(amt_out2 > amt, "Lost in arb");
}
function arb2(uint amt) public{
    uint amt_out = test.xxx2(amt, 0);
    uint amt_out2 = curve.exchange(1, 0, amt_out, 0);
    require(amt_out2 > amt, "Lost in arb");
}
}

interface IERC20 {
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
}

interface ICurve {
function exchange(uint i, uint j, uint dx, uint min_dy) payable external returns (uint dy);
}
interface Itest {
function xxx1(uint in, uint min_out) external returns (uint out);
function xxx2(uint in, uint min_out) external returns (uint out);
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I didn't need the approve function, did he just call that and then call transferFrom from his contract? Wow what a fail on my end.

Comment: yeah, looks like its the issue. Once approve transaction is finalized, he could just call transferFrom to drain your contract.

Answer (score 2):

Without you giving us tx-hash details, it is hard to find what exactly caused the hack. But I guess you do not have any reentrancy guard in your transfer function-- it might be why your contract is drained.

Another guess is your approve function takes an arbitrary contract address as an input without any sanity check. What if attacker passed your token address and approved herfself as a spender? Once the approve transaction is mined, he could have transferred the balance using transferFrom.

If you dont want to share transaction the details, use [tenderly](https://tenderly.co/)
to get better idea about what really happened.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the transfer function is public, not "only owner". I still don't know what the reentrancy guard is, I clearly have some reading to do.

Comment: This is what I was talking about:  https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/security

Answer (score 0):

Hacker approved spending of your contract tokens by calling arb.approve with spender of his address. When he calls it msg.sender was arb contract.

At the end we have allowance[arb][hacker]=uint256

Then he simply trasferFrom to himself by approved token interface;

Making arb.approve spender address as input and public at the same time wasnt a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, especially since I don't need approve at all, since I can call them in the constructor.